# Need to add prefix to captured names, based on given lists

Tags: regex, perl

I have two arrays @Mister and @Mrs and need to add prefix based on the   values.

```
@Mister = qw(Parasuram Raghavan Srivatsan);
@Mrs = qw(Kalai Padmini Maha);

my $str = "I was invited the doctor Parasuram and Kalai and civil Engineer Raghavan and Padmini and finally Advocate Srivatsan and Maha";

#Mr. Parasuram Mr. Raghavan Mr. Srivatsan
if(grep ($_ eq $str), @Mister)
{ $str=~s/($_)/Mr. $1/g; }

#Mrs. Kalai Mrs. Padmini Mrs. Maha` 
if(grep ($_ eq $str), @Mrs)
{ $str=~s/($_)/Mrs. $1/g; }
```

Output Should be:

`I was invited the doctor Mr. Parasuram and Mrs. Kalai and civil Engineer Mr. Raghavan and Mrs. Padmini and finally Advocate Mr. Srivatsan and Mrs. Maha`

Could someone simplify the way I am doing and whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple take

```
my $mr_re  = join '|', @Mister;
my $mrs_re = join '|', @Mrs;

$str =~ s/\b($mr_re)\b/Mr. $1/g;
$str =~ s/\b($mrs_re)\b/Ms. $1/g;
```

(note that I used the neutral `Ms` above instead of `Mrs`)

However, when we consider the bewildering complexity of names, the `\b` doesn't take care of all ways for a name to contain another. An easy example: the `-` is readily found in names and `\b` is an anchor between `\w` and `\W`, where `\w` does *not* include `-`.

Thus `Name-Another` would be matched by `Name` alone as well.

If there are characters other than alphanumeric (plus `_`) that can be inside names consider

```
my $w_re = /[a-z-]/i;  # list all characters that can be in a name

$str =~ s/(?<!$w_re)($mr_re)(?!$w_re)/Mr. $1/g;  # same for Ms.
```

where negative [lookarounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `?<!` and `?!` are assertions that match your non-name characters (those not listed in `$w_re`) but do not consume them. Thus they delimit acceptable names.

The same holds for accents, and yet many other characters used in names in various cultures. The task of forming a satisfactory `$w_re` may be a tricky one even for one particular use case.

If names can come in multiple words (with spaces), in order to handle names within others you would have to parse them in general. That is a complex task; seek modules as little regex won't cut it.

A simple fix would be to preprocess lists to check for names with multiple words that contain other names from your lists, and to handle that case by case.

---

For your example with hard coded and verifiable names the above works. However, in general, when assembling a regex from strings make sure that all (ascii) non-word chars are escaped so that you actually have the intended literal characters without a special meaning

```
my $mr_re  = join '|', map { quotemeta } @Mister;
my $mrs_re = join '|', map { quotemata } @Mrs;
```

See [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html); inside a regex use `\Q`, see it [in perlbackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Modifiers) and [in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters).

---

Note that this problem critically relies on sensible input.

If names are duplicated in lists the problem is ill-posed: If they repeat in the sentence  it is unknown which is which, if they don't it is unknown whether it is Mr. or Ms.  Thus the name lists should be first checked for duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

"Could someone simplify the way I am doing and whats wrong in this code."

The first part is addressed by zdim in a way I would do it too, but the "what's wrong" part could get some more addressing, in my opinion (just nitpicking, but maybe useful for someone):

`if(grep ($_ eq $str), @Mister)
 { $str =~ s/($_)/Mr. $1/g; }`

- Your list entries will never equal the $str, I think you meant `$str =~/$_/`
- Either use an additional pair of parenthesis around both condition and @list or use the block form of grep (`grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @Mister`) - otherwise grep will miss the list as argument, since it takes the one existing pair as limiter for it's argument list right now.
- the $_ used in the grep command is not available outside of the command, so the $str-substitution would use whatever the value of $_ is currently. In the example it would most likely be `undef`, so that between each character in the former $str 'Mr. ' is inserted.

Like I said: A perfectly good solution to your problem is given in zdim's answer, but you also asked "what's wrong in this code".

Answer (score 1):

@ssr1012 and other readers: Be careful! It's tempting to think there is a universal solution for this problem. But, unfortunately, even @zdim's approach will give undesirable results if the same name appears in both arrays, and it is still tricky if a name in one array is the same as a name in the other array except for a few additional characters at the start or end.
Here's your example using slightly different names:

```
my @Mister = qw(Parasuram Mahan Srivatsan);
my @Mrs = qw(Kalai Padmini Maha);
...

# I was invited the doctor Mr. Parasuram and Ms. Kalai and civil Engineer Mr. Ms. Mahan and Ms. Padmini and finally Advocate Mr. Srivatsan and Ms. Maha
```

See the "Mr. Ms. Mahan"? You don't have enough information for a universal solution. This is only reliable if your names are hard-coded and checked first to avoid collisions.

Even if you added first names, you might not have enough information - guessing gender from first names is unreliable in many language cultures.

Comment: I Understood your concern. Thanks we will check.

Comment: Good thoughts, but: (1) names within others in the scope of your example are readily solved, see edits to my answer (should've been there to start with, true). (2) Duplicated names simply mark an ill-posed problem. So yes, the lists should be compared for duplicates first. But having full names solves that as they are not duplicates then; which is Mr./Ms. is given, no need to guess. (3) On the other hand, the real problem starts when we consider names with multiple words (commented on in my answer)

Comment: @zdim: we are not in disagreement, but experience has taught me not to assume "... having full names solves that as they are not duplicates then;" -- in languages I work with (mainly English and Spanish) full names can still be ambiguous as to gender, and a dataset more than trivially small may have duplicate names. One Sydney Smith uses 'Ms." for their title, another Sydney Smith uses "Dr.", and a third Sydney Smith uses "Mr.". I say "lacks enough information", same as you say "the problem is ill-posed." One hopes IRL each record has a unique identifier not based only on names.

Comment: Agreed, names are hard to get right in general, no question.  I am saying that these are distinct points: If names are duplicated then the problem is just ambiguous (under-determined, more information needed, ill-posed ... :) -- otherwise it's all well and doable. Except for the bad situation, in an otherwise well-defined problem, when there are names with multiple words that may also contain each other.